# Can I integrate speech recognition with C#?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

Can I integrate speech recognition with C#? I want to develop an application that would recognize our dialect. I'm still collecting audio files to make it speaker independent.

1. What model should I use? Language or acoustic?
2. What tool would you recommend?

Comment: What platform(s) do you need to support? I believe the answers would vary based on those needs. Also - do you want to use a library or write this by yourself?

Comment: From what I've research, indeed there is a library for speech recognition and also built-in languages that the system might recognize. But In my case, they don't support our language. I guess I need to build it myself. Do you have any suggestion? Thanks.

Comment: @BoyKarton One minor note. The system will automatically insert line breaks into your question when you press enter a few times (just like you would typing in a word), so you don't need to worry about putting in `<br>` yourself.

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano Thanks for the note. I'm new here in SO. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the [Microsoft Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663%28VS.85%29.aspx)? MSDN includes a [C# getting started tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378426.aspx).

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. Because every time I search for speech recognition, it only results to 'building acoustic/language model', training your computer and etc. Do you have any link of any tutorial of that? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the update but my problem is, it doesn't support our language, Filipino words. It doesn't have any built-in library that might support to recognize our language as far as I know.

Comment: You could try contacting Nuance (www.nuance.com). Their Recognizer product understands 79 languages, but sadly not Filipino.

Answer (score 1):

Writing a speech-recognition system is a VERY complex topic and many papers have been written on the subject. Here are some nice introductory papers:

1. http://www.speech-recognition.de/pdf/introSR.pdf
2. http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~mcollins/6864/slides/asr.pdf
3. http://www.cs.rochester.edu/u/james/CSC248/Lec12.pdf

While the above papers deal with the basics of spectral modeling, feature vector extraction, clustering and data-mapping, my pet approaches to such complex classification problems have always been neural network based. Here are a set of papers that deal with different NN based approaches:

1. http://www.cslu.ogi.edu/tutordemos/nnet_recog/recog.html
2. http://www.ll.mit.edu/publications/journal/pdf/vol01_no1/1.1.7.neuralnetworks.pdf
3. http://www.ru.lv/~peter/zinatne/ebooks/(Brain%20Study)_Speech%20Recognition%20using%20Neural%20Networks.pdf
4. http://www.cs.toronto.edu/~ruiyan/csc411/ANNSpeechRecognition.pdf

I would advise you to start small and build the system in little steps. Good luck!

Just out of curiosity - what language *do* you need to support?

Comment: +1 for the papers and because I'm curious about the language as well.

Comment: Yea. I am planning on making just a small application first. I'm still new in speech recognition though. I want to support Filipino words, I'm from Philippines. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @BoyKarton Have you seen [this](http://www.eee.upd.edu.ph/content/speaker-independent-continuous-speech-recognition-filipino-speech-corpus)?

Comment: @RicardoAltamirano Yes. But the pdf file is not available. And no contact are being provided in the site. Thanks for the link.